# How do I move an object to a destination that is stored on mouse click?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to achieve the simplest thing. I have code for moving an object smoothly, and I want it to stop at a specific distance in relation to where the object was when the button was clicked. So I can't store the position inside any function that updates every frame. Currently the object simply starts moving and doesn't stop.

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        if (movement == true)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
        }
    }

    public void coroutineStarter()
    {
        float targetPosition = transform.position.x - 1;
        StartCoroutine(OnClick(targetPosition));
    }



    IEnumerator OnClick(float targetPosition)
    {
        if (transform.position.x != targetPosition)
        {
            movement = true;
        }
        else
        {
            movement = false;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I should specify that pressing the button starts the `coroutineStarter`. I tried to use a while loop instead of the if statement inside `OnClick` but apparently using while loops anywhere freezes unity if it's infinite, and if it isn't it freezes unity for the duration of the loop.

Comment: it doesn't freeze Unity if you `yield return null;` within it .. which tells Unity to pause the routine, render the frame and continue in the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix up a Coroutine with code running in `Update`. A Coroutine already is like a temporary `Update` method so you could simply do

```
public void coroutineStarter()
{
    var targetPosition = transform.position + Vector3.left;
    StartCoroutine(OnClick(targetPosition));
}

IEnumerator OnClick(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    while (transform.position.x != targetPosition)
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);

        // Important! Tells Unity to pause here, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // When done set the position fixed once
    // since == has a precision of 0.00001 so it never reaches an exact position
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

This moves the object to the target position with a constant speed.

---

A slightly different approach is moving the object within a certain time but allows to add ease-in and ease-out at start and end of the movement using `Vector3.Lerp` and `SmoothStep`

```
IEnumerator OnClick(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    var startPosition = transform.position;
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(startPosition, targetPosition);

    if(distance <= 0) yield break;

    var duration = distance / speed;
    var timePassed = 0f;

    while (timePassed < duration)
    {
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // Optionally add easing
        factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0,1,factor);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPosition, factor);

        // increase by time since last frame avoiding overshooting
        timePassed += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, duration - timePassed);

        // Important! Tells Unity to pause here, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // When done set the position fixed once
    // this time just in case you never know ;)
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```